# Need pass for public file express

Tags: express, path

When I call command `pwd` in the folder from which I want to get access to my public file(folder from which my project start), it returns me `/root/file/file`. I want to get file us public by using express. For this purpose I have to use :

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../photo')))
```

How to get a path to this file? My photos in `root/photo`